# How to correctly use the global operators new, new[], delete and delete[]

Tags: c++

I have a question (1 post per question, I learnt my lesson...) about using the global operators new, new[], delete and delete[] but first, I'll describe the situation.

In Herb Sutter's Exceptional C++ book, in the item 12 - Writing Exception-Safe Code—Part 5, the author uses these following pieces of code :

```
...
template <class T>
StackImpl<T>::StackImpl( size_t size )
    : v_( static_cast<T*>
            ( size == 0
            ? 0
            : operator new(sizeof(T)*size) ) ),
    vsize_(size),
    vused_(0)
{
} 

template <class T>
StackImpl<T>::~StackImpl()
{
    destroy( v_, v_+vused_ ); // this can't throw
    operator delete( v_ );
}
...

// construct() constructs a new object in
// a given location using an initial value
//
template <class T1, class T2>
void construct( T1* p, const T2& value )
{
    new (p) T1(value);
}

// destroy() destroys an object or a range
// of objects
//
template <class T>
void destroy( T* p )
{
    p->~T();
}

template <class FwdIter>
void destroy( FwdIter first, FwdIter last )
{
    while( first != last )
    {
        destroy( &*first );
        ++first;
    }
}
```

I didn't fully understand it at first, so I did a little test :

```
struct OperatorTest
{
    OperatorTest()
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    ~OperatorTest()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
    }

    OperatorTest&  operator=(const OperatorTest& other)
    {
        std::cout << "Assignment" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Operator new[]
    OperatorTest* test1 = static_cast<OperatorTest*>(operator new[](sizeof(OperatorTest) * 5)); // Only allocate memory
    new (&test1[0]) OperatorTest(); // Calls the constructor by doing a placement new
    test1[0].~OperatorTest(); // Calls the destructor
    operator delete[](test1); // Calls the destructor... again

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Operator new
    OperatorTest* test2 = static_cast<OperatorTest*>(operator new(sizeof(OperatorTest) * 5)); // Only allocate memory
    new (&test2[0]) OperatorTest(); // Calls the constructor by doing a placement new
    test2[0].~OperatorTest(); // Calls the destructor
    operator delete(test2); // Calls the destructor... again

    std::cout << std::endl;

    {
        // How does the STL allocate memory?
        std::vector<OperatorTest> test3{ 3 }; // Allocate memory and calls the default constructor
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Manual new[] / delete[]
    OperatorTest* test4 = new OperatorTest[3];
    delete[] test4;

    return 0;
}
```

The results of the main function in console is :

1. Constructor
2. Destructor
3. Constructor
4. Destructor
5. Constructor
6. Constructor
7. Constructor
8. Destructor
9. Destructor
10. Destructor
11. Constructor
12. Constructor
13. Constructor
14. Destructor
15. Destructor
16. Destructor

My questions is :

Are the variables test1 and test2 correctly created and destructed? One reason why I'm insecure about this is that both the array and single new / delete operators seem to work for an array.

My reasoning is that even the STL does not seem to use those operators. See the variable `test3` and its output as example.

Comment: Seriously, I'd like to know why I'm getting downvoted. I'd really like to improve my question to make it more readable for everyone and easier to understand.

Comment: Why does the third example show that the stadard library does not use `operator new[]`? The vector has to construct 3 objects, because you asked it to, while your other two examples construct only one object, even if space for 5 was allocated. (Questions about whether this code has the expected behavior defined aside.) Also `operator delete` does not call the destructor, which is why you need to do it manually beforehand.

Comment: @eukaryota It was a test to see how the STL's vector would act if I simply wanted to reserve space for 3 variables. Maybe it's my background in Java that's altering how I think it should act. So technically, it's what I wanted. I'll add this example.

Comment: `std::vector<OperatorTest> test3{ 3 };` and `new OperatorTest[3];` both allocate for (at least) 3 objects of type `OperatorTest` and construct exactly 3 such objects. `std::vector` can be made to only allocate, but not construct, with `std::vector<OperatorTest> test3; test3.reserve(3);` and you will see no construction or destruction happening, but even then it doesn't tell you anything about how the allocation happened.

Comment: @eukaryota Hmmm I guess I should have looked more in depth at the documentation. It is said that the default constructor does not allocate memory. I was sure that it was, again because I have a Java background.

Comment: The constructor (of any kind) is not responsible for allocating memory for the object itself. That happens before, e.g. `new OperatorTest[3];` first calls some variant of `operator new[]` (its a bit technical) which allocates the memory and then calls the default constructor three times in sequence with a `this` pointer to each of three subblocks in the allocated block. If any exceptions happen in any of the constructors it rolls-back (by calling the destructor) the already constructed ones and calling `operator delete[]` to free the memory again, so that this is exception-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of the operators new and delete (and their array versions) seem to be correct.

Your code comments ("Calls the destructor... again") indicate a misunderstanding. You seem to assume that the global operator delete will not only deallocate memory but also call the destructor of an object. This is not the case. The global operators new and delete only allocate/deallocate raw bytes, as the c-functions malloc and free do.

In this sense, both operator versions (single vs. array) do effectively the same, only they should match, i.e. a chunk of memory allocated by one version must be deallocated with the same version.